# Can I set a file to read-only without using a File object in Java?

Tags: java, file, security, metadata, inputstream

I'm using a system where we have built-in functionality to add Metadata tags to Jpeg images through the [Apache Commons Imaging library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/index.html).  This library allows for modification of Metadata directly through an InputStream.  This metadata is then read by [Symantec DLP](http://www.symantec.com/data-loss-prevention/) installed on our End User's machines to keep them from doing questionable things with tagged files(copy to flash, other storage, email, etc.).  The issue is that a user can still modify the tag after the fact because the file is writable, pretty much invalidating the security effort.

I'm looking to find out a way to write metadata for a file to become read-only in a similar fashion, by modifying the data through something that can wrap around an InputStream.

The Java [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) object has a built in method called setReadOnly() that could be used in theory, but the issue is that I'm never able to create a File object directly. We receive an InputStream from the client, modify it with other libraries, and encrypt it all before writing it to storage for security reasons.  If I add the tag to the encrypted file, it will be removed on decryption.  Apache Commons Imaging supports a host of metadata tag types, but I have been unsuccesful in finding any R/W tags supported.

Does anybody know how to set a File to be persistently read-only directly through an InputStream or some derived object using core Java, Apache Commons Imaging, or a useful third party library?

Comment: if you look at the source of `File.java` all it is doing is chmoding the file. You can do this yourself pretty easily by using something like [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

Comment: I am confused by the question. What is writing this to storage? Do you have access to the file?

Comment: Do you know where the image is stored to or have access it it? A read only file really is a OS concept, reacted to a given file on disk, without a reference to the  file it would be impossible to mark it as read only

Comment: Assuming I understand that the image is been stored in some kind of cloud service, then you would need to determine who to ask the service to make the file read only or provide read only access to the service for the users

Comment: "An `InputStream` or some derived object" does not have any sense of permissions of any kind.  No, you can't do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>You can do this really easily by just using `ProcessBuilder` to chmod the file.</strike>

Something like:

```
String fileLoc = "/var/tmp/myImage.jpg";
String[] cmd = {"chmod", "0444", fileLoc};
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
Process process = pb.start();
int error = process.waitFor();
if (error != 0){
    //non 0 means something bad happend
}
```

**EDIT:**
If you can't access it as a file, and only have it as a stream, you cannot set it to read only as that is a file system property, and nothing in the file actually changes.

Comment: He can't create the File object. So he can't a) get the path, and b) run something like chmod on that path.

Comment: other than this, I don't think there is anyway to set a file to readOnly as it is an OS flag, not a file flag afaik

Comment: Lol, then this isn't an answer to the question.

Comment: I misunderstood the question, in that case the answer is it is not possible as "read only" is something the FS handles.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I had the mistaken belief that you could make a file readonly through attributes of the file itself.  Didn't realize that if you want to change permissions, you'd need to do it on anywhere the file is transferred